# DataContractJsonSerializer ReadObject() returning null value

Tags: asp.net, .net, json

I am trying to deserialize JSON data so that i can insert the values into my database but i keep getting null values at  sts.text. Can someone assist? thanks

here is my data contract

```
[DataContract]
internal class Statuses
{
    [DataMember(Name = "text", IsRequired = false)]
    internal string text;
}


        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            Stream dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

            DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Statuses));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(responseFromServer));

            Statuses sts = (Statuses)js.ReadObject(ms);                
            Console.WriteLine("text: " + sts.text);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

Comment: What is the value of responseFromServer? I'm trying to test this but I need the JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    // Read the content.
    const string responseFromServer = "{\"text\":\"testing\"}"; //Add JSON

    var js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Statuses));
    var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseFromServer));

    var sts = (Statuses)js.ReadObject(ms);
    Response.Write("text: " + sts.text);
```

Also worth noting, I converted the *internal access modifier* with the *public access modifier*

```
[DataContract]
public class Statuses
{
    [DataMember(Name = "text", IsRequired = false)]
    public string text;
}
```

Also note that I changed:

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(responseFromServer)
```

With:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseFromServer)
```

And the final output that I got from my test was:

**text: testing**